# How to create a class extension in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to create my custom service via using `userManager`. But I don't know how to access to `dbContext`.

```
public static class UserManagerExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IdentityResult> AddProfileAsync(this UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, UserProfileModel model)
    {

        // how to access to dbContext here???

        if (await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }

        return IdentityResult.Failed();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(UserProfileModel model)
    {
        await _userManager.AddProfileAsync(model);

        return View();
    }
}
```

How to access `DbContext` class inside a static class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject it into your controller and then pass it to your method:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserController(DbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(UserProfileModel model)
    {
        await _userManager.AddProfileAsync(_dbContext, model);

        return View();
    }
}
```

That way, you have full control over where there database context comes from and with what kind of lifetime it exists.

If your goal is to actually create *a service* as you say, you should do so and not work with extension methods at all. You could do this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProfileService _profileService;

    public UserController(ProfileService profileService)
    {
        _profileService = profileService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(UserProfileModel model)
    {
        await _profileService.AddProfileAsync(model);
        return View();
    }
}

public class ProfileService
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileService(DbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> AddProfileAsync(UserProfileModel model)
    {
        // do stuff
        if (await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }
        return IdentityResult.Failed();
    }
}
```

And don’t forget to register your service in `Startup.ConfigureServices` using:

```
services.AddTransient<ProfileService>();
```

That way, you now have an actual service which has clear dependencies and which you can test properly, and you are also moving more logic out of your controllers which makes it easier to reason about it.

Comment: Thank you! I still have a small trouble. By the second, it's very clear but it seems like `User manager` doesn't `manage` the `user profile`. Something goes wrong, right? :))

Comment: @Vayne I don’t think I understand what you are saying? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best to only create a DbContext as needed and discard after "SaveChanges". To be able to create it you just need a connection string, which is usually something you store in a central configuration store.