# How to access EFCore context after initiating .Net Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm in need to Access the EFCore Context after initiating or starting the API.

I wan't to load some Settings from my Database to configure some Services. 
It would be good to load this settings just one time so like loading it in a Singleton Service which holds and provides them after that.

I can't find a good solution to just use the Context after the Startup of the API.

A simple solution would be great just something like this (If this is even possible somehow):

```
BuildWebHost(args).Run();
// I wan't to call the function something like this after starting/running/iniating the api
AppSettingsManager.LoadSettings(MyContext);
```

Would be great if someone can tell me how to achieve this or show me a Post, Blog or what ever that explains how to do this.

Comment: code first or db?

Comment: The linked questions are not *exact* duplicates but the mechanisms behind it should tell you how to do it: Basically, you want to use the options pattern for your configuration and then register an `IConfigureOptions<ApplicationOptions>` class via dependency injection. In that class, you can then inject the database context and use that to configure your `ApplicationOptions` instance. That way you can configure the options using data from the database.

Comment: ok I understood your Idea @poke on how to do this by DI with the Options Patter I would prefer a non DI way so I can use my AppSettingsManger deep within my BusinessLogic without passing it from the top level Controller or Class through all those complex functioncalls. Is there a Way to achiev this or is it still better to do this by DI and passing it throught by functions until I need it?

Comment: That would require your `AppSettingsManager` to be static/global and that is generally discouraged. One point of DI is to make dependencies explicit, and if you then have a single component that is a hidden dependency and used somewhere deep, then you are kind of defeating the whole point. – If you embrace DI properly, you do not need to pass it from the top yourself though. You can easily have a hiearchy like controller -> service A -> service B -> service C and only C has the dependency on the settings which is automatically fulfilled by DI. So you do not need to pass it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that Info. DO you now any good Article/Blog/what ever that explain how i can use this DI in "deep" service?

Comment: The [official docs on DI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) are pretty good at explaining how to use it, in particular the *“Registering Your Own Services”* section. For an example from myself, you could also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47346683/216074) which shows how to create a utility service. It is used directly in the controller there, but it could just as well be used in another service that is then used by the controller. (Basically, you just register everything via DI, and then just inject those dependencies you need).

Comment: thanks a lot @poke ! After reading that Docs-section and your Post I decided to rewrite a big part of our Application and start to use DI all ofer the place. Befor that I think it was hard to understand how Ef Core hadle the DI but now I'm in and its pretty nice to use it once you understood how it works!

Comment: That’s great to hear! I’m happy I could help you :)